# Why is rake doc:rails generating an invalid argument error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails and I was trying to download the API for the current project that I am working on. (I don't have internet access at all times.) When I run `rake doc:rails`;
I get this error.

`Generating SDOC format into C:/Users/Frank/work/project/doc/api/...`

`Invalid Argument-C:/Users/Frank/work/project/doc/api/files/C:`

does anybody know what to do about this?

Comment: I just got this same error as well. I'm on Windows 8 x64 and just installed ruby and rails via railsinstaller-windows 3.0.0-alpha2.

Comment: Here's the bug report. https://github.com/voloko/sdoc/issues/47  He has a modified version of the gem that's supposed to work under Windows. I haven't tried it though.